# How to create a boxplot for my dataset? (data transformation needed)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
              Measure
Code             
1200          55.122
1002          49.166
1002          49.263
1002          59.156
1200          49.353
1200          43.000
```

I want to create a box plot, so that X axis contains `Code` values and Y axis contains `Measurement` values as boxes (25th percentile, median, 75th percentile).

How can I do it?

This is what I tried, but it creates only 1 box in a plot instead of 2 boxes (for `Code` values `1002` and `1200`):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ds.boxplot(vert=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `index` and add parameter `by` to [`DataFrame.boxplot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ds.boxplot(vert=False,column='Measure', by='Code', ax=ax)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25)
```

[image: g]

Comment: This creates an empty plot for my real dataset. Do you know why it may happen?

Comment: @Fluxy - Are data numeric? What is `print (ds.info())` before my solution?

Comment: `Code` is object. Sorry, it was not clear at the beginning. I cannot convert it into integer, because it is actually a string.

Comment: @Fluxy - What is `print (ds.info())` ? I think `Measure` has to be numeric

Comment: @Fluxy - check code a bit and added picture of graph.

Comment: Now it worked. Thanks. Though there is no grid, no axes lines, only boxes. Also, do you know how to remove the fixed title "Boxplot grouped by Code"? I tried to pass `title` parameter, but it adds a subtitle.

Comment: @Fluxy - You can use `plt.suptitle("")`